# Yii2 allow post only data from model's scenario

Tags: php, yii2

I have ActiveRecord model `User` with this *scenarios()* method:

```
public function scenarios()
{   
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['create'] = ['username', 'email', 'password']; 
    return $scenarios;
}
```

Also, this model has *rules()* method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'required', 'on' => ['create']], 
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 3, 'max' => 55],
        ['email', 'required', 'on' => ['create']],
        ['email', 'email', 'on' => ['create']],
        ['password', 'required', 'on' => ['create']],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'on' => ['create']],
    ];
}
```

I want to deny post all data with keys that are not included in the  ***"create"*** scenario (allow receive only data with keys: *'username', 'email', 'password'*).

Right now i do it in `UserController` so:

```
...  
$activeAttributes = $model->activeAttributes();
$postParams = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();

foreach($postParams as $key=>$value){
  if(!(in_array($key, $activeAttributes))) throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Invalid attribute:' . $key);
}
...
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what's the advantage of that.

The user can post any data, but if it's strictly validated you have nothing to worry about.

If you nevertheless want to use it, your solution is OK, here are several remarks though:

- For getting `$_POST` data use high level method `\Yii::$app->request->post()` (it can return either all data, subarray or specific value). `getBodyParams()` is called inside of it.
- `404 Page Not Found` Exception is not suitable for this situation. I think `400 Bad Request` fits more.
- It's better to use built-in Yii2 wrappers for common exceptions, such as `BadRequestHttpException`. This way you don't worry about its code and thinking more about its meaning.
- `activeAttributes()` returns attribute names without values so you don't have to break iterated element in foreach into `$key` and `$value`.

So the code after these changes can be something like this:

```
$model = new YourModel(['scenario' => YourModel::SCENARIO_CREATE]);
$activeAttributes = $model->activeAttributes();

foreach (\Yii::$app->requst->post() as $attribute => $value) {
    if (!in_array($attribute, $activeAttributes)) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException("Invalid attribute: $attribute.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree with status "400 Bad Request". It is more appropriate in this situation. `Yii::$app->requst->post()` return post values in `$value` section, but we need compare keys of received data with values from activeAttributes().

Comment: @MaximChuprov Yes, missed that. Corrected the answer.